# How to save Python packages to Azure DevOps feed?

Tags: azure-devops

I created an Azure DevOps feed in my project and added pypi as an upstream source. I can see packages when searching upstream sources but this doesn't work when I use PipAuthenticate task with this feed. The package can't be found when running `pip install`. I believe I need to save the python package to my feed. But I can't see this option. The option dropdown only has `Show Details`. What configuration am I missing?

[image]